# Cron Expression - Start at 10:20 and execute each 10min until 19:00

Tags: cron

I have a case in which I'm migrating some tasks from Windows to a platform and we are using cron expressions to replace the Windows Scheduler.

Today we have something in Windows like `At 10:20 AM every weekday, every 10 minutes for 9 hours`. I'm trying to replace it with chron but I couldn't achieve it so far.

The closest I got is `0 20/10 10-19 * * MON-FRI`. The thing is on this cron, it won't execute at 11:00, 12:00 and so on. We have a specific case in which we don't want it to execute at 10:00 AM.

The only option I found is to execute at 10:00AM and put some condition to validate it. Is it possible to achieve this result with only chron?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with cron, but you'll need to break it up into two schedules.

[20/10 10 * * MON-FRI](https://crontab.guru/#20/10_10_*_*_MON-FRI)

and

[*/10 11-19 * * MON-FRI](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_11-19_*_*_MON-FRI)

Btw, if this is cron on unix, there is no field for seconds.